# French term for "pre-order"?

Tags: traduction

Is there a common french phrase for "pre-order"?  Context:  "This product is not yet available, but can be pre-ordered".

Comment: Amazon uses the same that Google provides, "Pré-commander".  That seems too literal to me as it is using the sense "command" rather than "purchase"

Comment: "commander" is a correct translation for "to order" here. "To purchase" would be "acheter" which is not yet the case with a "pre-order".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On peut utiliser "précommande" s'il s'agit d'un bien matériel en quantité "illimitée" (téléphone, jeux), ou "réservation" pour des quantités limitées (place de concert, chambre d'hôtel).

---

You use "précommande" for items in big quantity (soon to be released smart phone, next hype game). You will use "réservation" for limited quantity items (hotel room).

According to comment, "précommande" is related to items which don't exist yet (such as a next phone).

Comment: Je n'aurais pas mis la distinction entre "précommande" et "réservation" sur les quantités, mais plutôt sur le paiement à l'avance. Tu peux très bien réserver ou précommander un jeu, mais je m'attends dans le cas d'une précommande à devoir payer l'entièreté (comme le processus de commande futur, mais à l'avance) tandis que dans le cas d'une réservation je m'attends à payer à l'avance au maximum les frais de réservation. Cela dit, je ne sais même pas si une telle distinction existe et si les 2 termes ne peuvent pas être considérés comme synonymes.

Comment: "réserver" implique une possible pénurie, donc une quantité limité (hôtel, concert). Pour un jeu ou un téléphone la quantité est (presque) "illimité", on peut utiliser réserver ou précommander. Je n'ai jamais précommandé une nuit d'hôtel.

Comment: _Précommande_ : [_Larousse_](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/précommande), [_Termium_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=PRECOMMANDE), [_GDT_ (plus ancien)](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8981484).

Comment: I don't get the distinction you're trying to make here. “Précommande” is also used for physical items, even if only a limited series will be manufactured. It is not used for things like hotel rooms, but neither is “preorder” in English: “réservation (fr)” corresponds to “booking (en)”.

Comment: Sans césure. Oui?